IntersectionObserver при перезагрузке страницы в месте наблюдаемого объекта срабатывает только при скролле страницы, а не сразу
Пытаюсь сделать lazy loading картинок с помощью IntersectionObserver. Когда просто листаешь страницу до места с картинкой, все подгружается нормально. Однако когда перезагружаешь страницу в месте с незагруженной картинкой, при перезагрузке картинка подгружается только при скролле страницы вверх-вниз, хотя картинка находится в поле видимости обсервера. Можно ли тут что-то сделать? Чтобы обсервер сразу видел, что картинку уже надо загрузить при перезагрузке?
<img class="lazy" data-src="girl (2).png" src="back.png" alt="">
<img class="lazy" data-src="comf-1.png" src="back.png" alt="">
<img class="lazy" data-src="comf-2.png" src="back.png" alt="">
<img class="lazy" data-src="yoga.png" src="back.png" alt="">

const Images = document.querySelectorAll('img[data-src]');
function loadImages(entries) {
    if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
        entries[0].target.src = entries[0].target.dataset.src
        observer.unobserve(entries[0].target)   
    }
}
    
const options = {
    threshold: 0,
    rootMargin: '50px'
}
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(loadImages, options)
    
Images.forEach(img => {
    observer.observe(img)
})



А чем стандартный браузереный способ не угодил? https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#loading

У тебя при перезагрузке страницы срабатывает entries[0].isIntersecting +  observer.unobserve(entries[0].target)  соответственно ты отписываешься отслеживания

@Алексей 13, все равно не прогружается, даже если убрать observer.unobserve(entries[0].target)

@Qwertiy, спасибо, посмотрю

@Алексей 13, получается, когда есть только одна картинка, при перезагрузке все срабатывает (при наличии observer.unobserve(entries[0].target) и без), но когда две картинки и больше, стоят колонкой или в ряд вместе, то сначала observer срабатывает на одной, а потом надо поскроллить вверх-вниз, чтобы он сработал на второй.

@Алексей 13,  если поместить картинки в один контейнер, и уже на него повесить обсервер, то все срабатывает при перезагрузке страницы. Будет ли хорошим вариантом вешать обсервер на секции, где есть картинки?

Обсервер должен быть на каждую картинку, все верно. По идее тебе нужно в фориче   проверить, находится ли изображение в области видимости( через getBoundingClientRect) если находится, устанавливать src и делать анобсерв, иначе обсерв

@Алексей, спасибо, буду пробовать

Надо сделать проверку, есть ли картинка в области видимости (решение подсказали в комментариях выше), с помощью координат картинки и окна браузера.
Если находится, значит вставляем в аттрибут src данные из data-аттрибута, и снимаем с картинки обсервер. Вставляем функцию в цикл forEach для массива картинок:
function visibleCheck(target) {
    let targetTop = target.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset
    let targetBottom = target.getBoundingClientRect().bottom + window.pageYOffset

    let windowTop = window.pageYOffset
    let windowBottom = window.pageYOffset + document.documentElement.clientHeight

    if (targetTop < windowBottom || targetBottom > windowTop) {
        target.src = target.dataset.src
        observer.unobserve(target)
    }
}

Images.forEach(img => {
    observer.observe(img)
    visibleCheck(img)
})

